# VBA my macro duplicates the outcome of the if statement if changed

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, duplicates, range

What it does is just check the if statements and if not in this case "Nee" then write a sentence in O.

My problem: If all the cells are already filled in, and one cell needs to be changed. The macro will change other cells outcomes to which it shouldn't do and it will create duplicates.

This is how it should be when everything is filled in and if I change a cell.
[Like it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkSZZ.png)

This is how it is after I change a cell like I did in L6.
[After I changed the value in L6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuEvd.png)
It duplicates in cell O6 and in cell O4 he duplicates that too.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D2:L102"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call SampleMacro
    End If

End Sub

Sub SampleMacro()

    ' Get the last row
    Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    startRow = 2
    lastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = startRow To lastRow

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in D column, then append next sentence
    If Sheet3.Range("D" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = "? Er wordt in de cookie policy niet uitgelegd wat cookies zijn."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("D" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = "? Er wordt in de cookie policy matig uitgelegd wat cookies zijn."
    End If

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in E column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("E" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Waarom ze nuttig zijn is hier niet omschreven."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("E" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Waarom ze nuttig zijn is hier matig omschreven."
    End If

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in F column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("F" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De soorten cookies die worden gebruikt zijn niet uitgelegd."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("F" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De soorten cookies die worden gebruikt zijn matig uitgelegd."
    End If

    ' If there's Nee/Matig in G column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("G" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De doeleinden zijn nergens terug te vinden."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("G" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? De doeleinden zijn matig beschreven."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in H column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("H" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Nergens wordt er gesproken over de bewaartermijn van de cookies."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("H" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Over de bewaartermijn van de cookies wordt matig gesproken."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in I column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("I" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Hoe we de cookie-instellingen kunnen wijzigen is nergens neergeschreven."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("I" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Hoe we de cookie-instellingen kunnen wijzigen is matig neergeschreven."
    End If

     'If there's Nee/Matig in J column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("J" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Hoe de cookiegegevens gewist kunnen worden is nergens te vinden."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("J" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Hoe de cookiegegevens gewist kunnen worden is matig te vinden."
    End If

     'If there's Nee/Matig in K column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("K" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Er wordt niet gesproken over derde partijen."
    ElseIf Sheet3.Range("K" & i).Value = "Matig" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Er wordt matig gesproken over derde partijen."
    End If

    'If there's Nee/Matig in L column, then append next sentence with new line (Chr(10))
    If Sheet3.Range("L" & i).Value = "Nee" Then
        Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value = Sheet3.Range("O" & i).Value & Chr(10) & "? Tenslotte is de verwerkingsverantwoordelijke niet aanwezig op het cookiebeleid."
    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I Believe you must disable events and refresh update because the changes the macro does will trigger the macro. `Application.EnableEvents= False` Try using this before calling the sample macro, and reenable the mafter the the sample macro is done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Damian! 

So you mean that the follow code needs to be before private sub or the sub sample macro():

Sub Appl_EnableEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D2:L102"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call SampleMacro
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

You do this to avoid the `SampleMacro` from triggering again the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Edited:

To avoid doing again cells already filled you must Aim to the row you changed like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D2:L102"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call SampleMacro(Target.Row)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This should be the code on the worksheet object. As you can see I'm including the `Target.Row` variable to the `SampleMacro` so the code only checks the row your cell have changed.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SampleMacro(i As Long)

    ' Get the last row
    Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer
    Set Sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BBDD") 'whatever is called your sheet

    With Sheet3
        For j = 4 To 12 'For columns D to J
            Select Case .Cells(i, j)
                Case "Nee" 'If the cells says "Nee"
                    Select Case j 'depending on the column number
                        Case 4 'Column D
                            .Cells(i, "O") = "? Er wordt in de cookie policy niet uitgelegd wat cookies zijn."
                        Case 5 'Column E

                        Case 6 'Column F

                        Case 7 'Column G

                        Case 8 'Column H

                        Case 9 'Column I

                        Case 10 'Column J

                        Case 11 'Column K

                        Case 12 'Column L

                    End Select
                Case "Matig" 'If the cells says "Matig"
                    Select Case j 'depending on the column number
                        Case 4 'Column D
                            .Cells(i, "O") = "? Er wordt in de cookie policy matig uitgelegd wat cookies zijn."
                        Case 5 'Column E

                        Case 6 'Column F

                        Case 7 'Column G

                        Case 8 'Column H

                        Case 9 'Column I

                        Case 10 'Column J

                        Case 11 'Column K

                        Case 12 'Column L

                    End Select
        Next j
    End With    

End Sub
```

I didn't finish the whole code, but I hope you get how to end it. `Select Case` is more readable in this case, I'm looping through columns D to L using the variable `j` and one select case checking what's inside the cell `"Nee"` or `"Matig"` and depending on which one then the other `Select Case` which checks the column number. With that your code will look cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: If I replace it, other cells still duplicate there outcome.

Comment: @Batty so you are just trying to get the macro to fill the row where you changed the cell, right? At the moment your macro changes everything within the range `"D2:L102"`so you should just stick to the target you are changing instead of the range.

Comment: Yes if a cell in a row is changed then the macro only needs to change the outcome in that row.

Comment: @Batty I've edited my answer. See if it fits your needs.

Comment: @Damien I see what you did and understand the code, thanks for all the help you already did today! Now my problem is that he can't find the Macro name? In my answer you will find a screenshot. I am sorry for being so unacknowledged in VBA and scripting I am just a starter.

Comment: To run a macro which has parameters you must call it from another macro like I did `Call SampleMacro(Target.Row)` since the macro is triggered by a cell change, just copy both codes where they belong (the one that triggers on cell change on the worksheet object) and the sample macro on a module.

Comment: The 2 blocks above are the ones I need to put in the VBA?

Comment: The 2 blocks after "Edited:" the shorter one on the worksheet object which will trigger the macro i.e. your data is in a sheet called  "Data Base" you will have an object called SheetX (Data Base) double click on it and paste the first block. The second one in a module.

Comment: Okey , I did what u said and the Macro still doesn't want to run. I'll post a screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

[Sheet 3 named "Cookie Policy", all the data is in this sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGyq0.png)

[Module 1 where the code is for worksheet 3 named "Cookie Policy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqBBY.png)

[The end of Module 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHpTh.png)

[Break at "Application.EnableEvents = False" then this pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h6P8.png)

Comment: Now go to your sheet policy and change the cell D2, it should trigger the macro. To check that, use a stop point on `Application.EnableEvents = False` then you can debug line by line (pressing F8) or from stop to stop (pressing F5)

Comment: I get the message box to run Macro but it can't find any. And if I edit cell D2 it does nothing.

Comment: Batty in your screenshoots the macro isn't finished. You should finish all the Select case.

Comment: Hey Damien, I just finished the Select cases. But it still wouldn't work. He just can't find any Macro.

Comment: Last thing you could try, when calling the sample macro... Try `Call Module1.SampleMacro(Target.Row)` but I don't get why it won't work... It did work on my workbook.

Comment: On the first block put a stop point  in `Application.EnableEvents = False` If you change something on your sheet, that line should be highlighted in yellow... If it's not happenning. Save your workbook and close every instance of excel you have, then reopen it again and try the same.

Comment: Added another photo.